# Extensional versus intensional theories in mathematics

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic, lambda-calculus

Lambda calculus is often cited as an intensional theory whereas set theory is cited as an extensional theory. What are other examples of extensional and intensional theories of mathematical logic?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See :

> Stewart Shapiro (editor), [Intensional mathematics](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0444876324) (1985)

and :

> Johan van Benthem, [A manual of intensional logic](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/093707330X) (2nd ed 1988).

Comment: Recommending books is very nice but a few words of explanation would be welcome.